# Getting error when I am trying to put expression inside a jinja template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to put an expression such as

```
"Host(`{{ .Name }}.access.{{website_tld}}`)"`
```

inside my jinja2 template `static_traefik.yml.j2` so that {{ .Name }} should stay as is but {{website_tld}} should get replaced when I am running ansible task.

However this is throwing a massive error:

```
"AnsibleError: template error while templating string: unexpected char '\\\\' at 1016.
consulCatalog:\n    defaultRule: f\"Host(`{{{{ \\.Name }}}}.access.{{website_tld}}`)\"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout jinja escaping
https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#escaping

So both would work:

```
"Host(`{% raw %}{{ .Name }}{% endraw %}.access.{{website_tld}}`)"
```

```
"Host(`{{ "{{ .Name }}" }}.access.{{website_tld}}`)"
```